# Does Kuwait airways honor full refund for cancelling flight within 24 hours since purchase?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, refunds

I was wondering if all the flights into and out of US have to follow the rule of full refund for cancellation of a flight within 24 hours of purchase?

I can't find it specified on the website of Kuwait airways and in the purchase conditions during placing an order. So does its refund policy include that?

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/179082/qantas-is-refusing-to-apply-dot-s-free-cancellation-within-24-hrs-policy

Comment: Note: it depends on where you bought the ticket (so which country law apply), how do you bought the ticket (laws changes, but I assume you are a private citizen, else ... rules are different but you may know better), and if you had special conditions (last minute tickets, etc.)

Comment: [Does the 24-hour grace period on U.S. air travel work on international itineraries?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/83240/1810)

Answer (score 2):

I would proceed with caution. Technically all flights to/from the US are covered but airlines are good at finding loopholes.

> All airlines operating to, from, and within the U.S. must comply with the 24-hour rule.

The only exemption are flights purchases less than 7 days before departure.

The airline can meet the rule either by allowing cancellation within 24 hours OR by allowing to hold a are for free for 24 hours. They do NOT have to do both.

There are also potential loopholes with code shares and buying tickets not directly with the airline (Expedia, Priceline, etc.). As far as I can tell Kuwait air is currently running at least one flight to the US (JFK) so they can't use the excuse of "not operating in the US".

Good practice is to check their website and terms and conditions

> According to the DOT, airlines have to be upfront with customers about the one-day refund grace period both on their websites and when they are contacted by passengers. This means that not only does an explanation of the 24-hour reservation requirements need to be visible in the refund policy sections of an airline’s website (like on any terms and conditions pages or booking pop-up windows), but customer service representatives must also explain the rule to passengers who call them with questions about canceling.

If you can't find anything on their website or their contract of carriage, than chances are they think they have a viable loophole. Of course, you can always pick up the phone and ask directly.

In case they refuse a refund your only option is to file a complaint with the DOT. If this will ever result in them taking action, an actual refund and how long that may take, is anyone's guess. I personally wouldn't rely on that.

Source: https://www.cntraveler.com/story/24-hour-flight-cancellation-rule

Comment: Thanks. See another case https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/179082/qantas-is-refusing-to-apply-dot-s-free-cancellation-within-24-hrs-policy?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment452811_179085

Comment: It would be great to see a follow up. Does a complain with the DOT actually makes anything happen ?

Comment: I didn't file any complaint. I bought and canceled Qatar Airline flight via flychina.